# Assign a variable by name in scilab

Tags: scilab

Given that I have a matrix of variable name strings and the respective values in another matrix (both come from a csv file), how can I create variables in the workspace that have the names from the name matrix and the values from the value matrix?

I have found `global` to define a variable's scope so that I can write to it in a function, but I haven't found a way to handle runtime variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `execstr` function (see: https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/execstr.html)

For example, with a matrix names stored in the variable `MatrixNames` and the matrix content stored in the variable `MatrixContent`, you will simply have:

```
execstr(MatrixName(i)+'= MatrixContent');
```

With `i` the cell number for the corresponding matrix name you want to treat.

Answer (score 1):

As @david-dorchies suggested, you should use [`execstr`](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/execstr.html). To make sure they are globally accesible use globals if you want to do it in a function.

See below for an example implementation.

```
funcprot(0);
clear;
function assign_to_globals(names, values)

        for i=1:length(values)
            execstr(sprintf('clearglobal %s; global %s;', names(i), names(i)))
            execstr(sprintf('%s = %s;', names(i), string(values(i))))
        end;

endfunction

function disp_all_globals(names)
    for i=1:(size(names,1)*size(names,2))
        disp(names(i))
        execstr(sprintf('global %s; disp(%s)', names(i), names(i)))
    end;
endfunction

values = list(23,5.6,6/10,"[1,2,3]");
names = ['a','my_long_var_name','c1','my_sub_mat'];

assign_to_globals(names, values)
disp_all_globals(names)

clearglobal()
```